# Awk/sed replace newlines

Tags: shell, csv, awk, replace

### Intro:

I have been given a CSV file in which the field delimiter is the pipe characted (i.e., `|`).
This file has a pre-defined number of fields (say `N`). I can discover the value of `N` by reading the header of the CSV file, which we can assume to be correct.

### Problem:

Some of the fields contain a newline character by mistake, which makes the line appear shorter than required (i.e., it has `M` fields, with `M < N`).

What I need to create is a `sh` script (not `bash`) to fix those lines.

### Attempted solution:

I tried creating the following script to try fixing the file:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
    exit
fi

# get first line
first_line=$(head -n 1 $1)

# get number of fields
num_separators=$(echo "$first_line" | tr -d -c '|' | awk '{print length}')

cat $1  | awk -v numFields=$(( num_separators + 1 )) -F '|' '
{
    totRecords = NF/numFields
    # loop over lines
    for (record=0; record < totRecords; record++) {
        output = ""
        # loop over fields
        for (i=0; i<numFields; i++) {
            j = (numFields*record)+i+1 
            # replace newline with question mark
            sub("\n", "?", $j)
            output = output (i > 0 ? "|" : "") $j 
        }
        print output
    }
}
'
```

However, the newline character is still present.
How can I fix that problem?

### Example of the CSV:

```
FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|NOTES
John|Smith|This is a field with a
newline
Foo|Bar|Baz
```

### Expected output:

```
FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|NOTES
John|Smith|This is a field with a * newline
Foo|Bar|Baz

* I don't care about the replacement, it could be a space, a question mark, whatever except a newline or a pipe (which would create a new field)
```

Comment: Can you include a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that if a field contains a line feed that the record will contain less fields then the header as will the next record(s)?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I will include it ASAP

Comment: @JNevill if I understood it right, yes: if line X contains a newline then lines X and X+1 will be shorter too. If line X contains 3 line feeds than lines X, X+1, X+2 and ax+3 will be shorter than required

Comment: As a clarification (emerged in comments on @JNevill's answer): all lines have the same number of fields, but some of the fields contain a newline/line feed. As a result, these lines are "split" across multiple lines. In other words, instead of having 1 line with 10 fields, you have 2 lines with, say, 7 and 3 fields.

Comment: If multiple lines are split after each other, it becomes really messy.  Challenging problem, this.  Why, by the way, do you call it a CSV file? It doesn't look comma-separated to me.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input.

Comment: Well, it's a "pipe-separated value". It's equivalent to a CSV, but with a different separator :)

Comment: @EdMorton I added the expected output, thanks!

Comment: W.r.t. the sample input, without further information I don't think there's anyway to know whether the extra newline was in the last field of the first record, or the first field of the second record. Of course as humans we can see you mean for it to be in the last field of the first record, but how would a program know?

Comment: @jas Good observation, I forgot to mention it. For what I know (I am not the producer of such file), the first field **should not** be inputed by a human (which has other input fields and can insert newlines by mistake), but it a sort of ID, so we can safely assume that the first field does not contain any weird character. In this scenario the error must reside in the last field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==1 { reqdNF = NF; printf "%s", $0; next }
{ printf "%s%s", (NF < reqdNF ? " " : ORS), $0 }
END { print "" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file.csv
FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|NOTES
John|Smith|This is a field with a newline
Foo|Bar|Baz
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and associated output.

Comment: This is much better +1

Comment: Excellent answer, I do not even need the "initialization" script. I didn't know `awk`, but I must admit that it is really powerful.

Comment: Yes it is. If you might have to do any text manipulation and can use a CLI I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: This is beautiful. I use awk for simple field cutting, but this is so elegant. Just bought the text @EdMorton recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that the last field may contain one newline. Using **tac** and **sed**:

```
tac file.csv | sed -n '/|/!{h;n;x;H;x;s/\n/ * /p;b};p' | tac
```

Output:

```
FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|NOTES
John|Smith|This is a field with a * newline
Foo|Bar|Baz
```

---

How it works.  Read the file backwards, **sed** is easier without forward references.  If a line has no '|' separator, `/|/!`, run the block of code in curly braces `{};`, otherwise just `p` print the line.  The block of code:

1. `h;` stores the delimiter-less line in `sed`'s *hold* buffer.
2. `n;` fetches another line, since we're reading backwards, this is the line that should be appended *to*.
3. `x;` exchange hold buffer and pattern buffer.
4. `H;` append pattern buffer *to* hold buffer.
5. `x;` exchange newly appended lines to pattern buffer, now there's two lines in one buffer.
6. `s/\n/ * /p;` replace the middle linefeed with a " * ", now there's only one *longer* line; and print.
7. `b` start again, leave the code block.

Re-reverse the file with `tac`; done.

Comment: Hi agc, thanks for the answer. The assumption on which your code is based is that the extra newline is in the last field, right?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to clear this point before using it :) Nice explanation, however!